# Group Axioms, Vector Space Axioms, Inner Product Axioms.

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, terminology, inner-products, axioms

This might be a slightly silly question, apologies for that.

Anyways, I have been studying Linear Algebra and some Group Theory at University over the last few months and I started wondering why Axioms like the group axioms, vector space axioms etc are axioms, rather than just conditions that mathematical objects satisfy.

The reason I ask this is because the Group axioms especially, seem to me no different, in type, from say the conditions which a bijective function satisfies or the conditions an odd number satisfies.

So my main question is , why are group axioms, vector space axiom, inner product axioms, etc called axioms rather than simply conditions.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Short answer: they **are** just conditions for mathematical objects to satisfy! There is a lot of study of these objects, and entire theories built around them. A lot of people study these objects completely abstractly, and these properties are all that people are allowed to assume of them, so we call them 'axioms'.

Comment: Cheers, that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no hard-and-fast rule, here is a possible distinction between the use of *axioms* and *conditions*. The term *axioms* tends to be used when defining a very general object or theory, so that the vector space axioms define what it means to be a vector space. Once the general theory has been outlined, special objects are identified by satisfying certain *conditions* or *properties*. Thus we might first give group axioms and then later specify the conditions for a group to be *abelian*. I suppose you could say that axioms are foundational and set the context, whereas conditions are the features some subsequent objects of study might or might not enjoy.